# TypeError: unorderable types: float() < function()

Tags: python, function, numpy

I have a code comprised of two functions one that reads data and the other that counts it. Both functions run properly when run separately, but I get the error when I try to have the counter call the file reader. I would appreciate it if some one could tell me where I am goofing up. Thanks in advance

Error

```
File "C:\Documents and Settings\Read_File.py", line 50, in counter
Sx = ((25. < Xa) & (Xa < 100.)).sum()    #count what is in x range
TypeError: unorderable types: float() < function()
```

Code

```
for line in f:        #Loop Strips empty lines as well as replaces tabs with space
if line !='':    
  line = line.strip()
  line = line.replace('\t',' ')
  columns = line.split()
  for line in range(N):       #Loop number of lines to be counted
   x = columns[8]             # assigns variable to columns
   y = columns[18]
   z = columns[19]
   #vx = columns[]
   #vy = columns[]
   #vz = columns[]
   X.append(x)
   Y.append(y)                #appends data in list
   Z.append(z)
  
 Xa = numpy.array(X, dtype=float)                   #Converts lists to NumPy arrays
 Ya = numpy.array(Y, dtype=float)
 Za = numpy.array(Z, dtype=float)



 return(Xa,Ya,Za)         #returns arrays/print statement to test 
   
 
def counter(Xa):
 Sx = ((25. < Xa) & (Xa < 100.)).sum()    #count what is in x range
 Sy = ((25. < Ya) & (Ya < 100.)).sum()    #count what is in y range
 Sz = ((25. < Za) & (Za < 100.)).sum()    #count what is in z range

 return(print(Sx,Sy,Sz))

read_file(F)                              #function calls 
counter(read_file)
```

**EDit**

With the help of Lev and James the first problem was fixed now I get this error

```
  Sx = ((2. < Xa) & (Xa < 10.)).sum()    #count what is in x range
  TypeError: unorderable types: float() < tuple()
```

Is this because of the commas in the arrays? And if so how can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call `counter()` on the *function `read_file()`*, not on the results of calling `read_file(F)`. You don't include source for `read_file()`, but you almost certainly want to do:

```
counter(readfile(F))
```

instead of the last two lines. (By the way, the `result(print(...))` in `counter()` probably doesn't need the `return` wrapping round the rest of it.)

Comment: I have run in to another error code `Sx = ((2. < Xa) & (Xa < 10.)).sum()    #count what is in x range
  TypeError: unorderable types: float() < tuple()

Is this because of the commas in the arrays? And if so how can I get around this?`

Comment: `counter()` should take three arguments, and then you invoke it as `counter(*read_file(F))`. Really that's a completely separate question, however.

Comment: It unpacks the list or tuple into separate arguments when it calls the function. See the python documentation at <http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists>.

Comment: I had given it three arguments at first, but changed it to one when I was testing it and never put the Ya and Za back in. The `counter(*read_file(F))` fixed it, but now I get this error `Sx = ((2. < 10) & (1 < 10.)).sum()    #count what is in x range
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'sum'`

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying to fix the problem you ask; overall you have a bigger problem which is that you're approaching the problem in a way that doesn't really make sense. I *think* you want to do something like Sx = len(filter(lambda v: 25. < v && v < 100., Xa), but honestly I didn't look beyond the immediately errors you were seeing.

Comment: thank you for all the help maybe I will rewrite it I am just confused by the fact that the functions separately work perfectly.

Comment: I figured it out I was using the wrong columns and hence getting the wrong answers. Thank for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
    Sx = sum(item for item in Xa if 25. < item < 100.)
```

... and so on and so forth.

Basically you're iterating through each item in `Xa` and omitting the ones that don't fall with the range. Then you're summing them.

P. S. You're getting the error because float() and tuple() types don't have a defined comparison function.